# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to include on my website the Quicksand script, but I failed badly.
Firebug gives me this error: `65 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined`:

for this script:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // Clone applications to get a second collection
    var $data = $("#portfolio-items").clone();

    //NOTE: Only filter on the main portfolio page, not on the subcategory pages
    $('#portfolio-terms ul li').click(function(e) {
        $("ul li").removeClass("active");   
        // Use the last category class as the category to filter by. This means that multiple categories are not supported (yet)
        var filterClass=$(this).attr('class').split(' ').slice(-1)[0];
jquery.custom.js:65 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined (repeated 6 times)

        if (filterClass == '.all current') {
            var $filteredData = $data.find('#portfolio-');
        } else {
            var $filteredData = $data.find('#portfolio-[data-type=' + filterClass + ']');
        }
        $("#portfolio-items").quicksand($filteredData, {
            duration: 800,
            easing: 'swing',
        });     
        $(this).addClass("active");             
        return false;
    });
});
```

See here: http://stakk.it/ 
what is the error?
thank you and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Why would you think that filterClass could possibly equal `.all current`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If `.attr("class")` returns `undefined`, you can't call `.split` on it because `.split` is a method of the `String` object and can't be called on `undefined`. You need to store the result of `.attr("class")` and then only split it if it is not `undefined`.

```
var filterClass = $(this).attr('class');
filterClass = filterClass ? filterClass.split(' ').slice(-1)[0] : '';
```

now filterClass will contain what you expect, or an empty string.

Edit: you could replace `$(this).attr('class')` with `this.className`, pulled from removed answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Now I solved the problem but I don't understand why the images vanish. You can see it here: http://stakk.it/

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is using `toString` method

```
  var filterClass = $(this).attr('class').toString();
   filterClass = filterClass.split(' ');
```

it worked for me