# JQuery .attr not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

Using JQuery I am searching for and outputting the src attribute from all scripts loaded on a page. Here is my code:

```
$('script').each(function(index, value) { 

    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    var src = src || 'no source';
    console.log(src);

}
```

An example script we are searching for:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://domain.co.uk/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.0'></script>
```

and console output would be:

```
http://domain.co.uk/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.0
```

This works fine and all these src's are being outputted. However there is one instance where I get an error. The problem arises when a script outputs javascript directly into the page which contains 'src'. In this instance I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

I can see this is because my code is picking up the src from within the ouputed javascript. I have included this Javascript at the bottom to help show exactly what I'm talking about.

The specific line is:   s.src = '//api.usersnap.com/load/47134af3-5898-4c09-88c9-6aed89cfac7f.js';

and just before the error the console.log outputs:

//api.usersnap.com/load/47134af3-5898-4c09-88c9-6aed89cfac7f.js

#### Summary

I thought .attr would only grab the attribute within the targeted element. How do I get it to do just that and ignore everything else which seems to be causing this error.

#### Offending Script Outputed

```
    <script type="text/javascript" data-cfasync="false">
                (function() {
                    var s = document.createElement('script');
                    s.type = 'text/javascript';
                    s.async = true;
                    s.src = '//api.usersnap.com/load/47134af3-5898-4c09-88c9-6aed89cfac7f.js';
                    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
                    x.appendChild(s);
                })();
    </script>
```

Comment: attr() is being deprectaed @Dimitri?

Comment: Thanks @Dimitri but I get the same problem with: var src = $(this).prop('src');

Comment: @Dimitri it is situationally dependent. Attributes and properties are being handled better by jQuery within their contexts.

Comment: Actually it works on jsfiddle when I include the script as a resource - http://jsfiddle.net/Nwk9r/

Comment: I don't see anything related to your code that would cause said error.

Answer (score 0):

When I try it, I have no problem outputting the src to all scripts on a page, including the one from the code you posted.

```
js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js script.js
//api.usersnap.com/load/47134af3-5898-4c09-88c9-6aed89cfac7f.js
```

I suggest you upgrade jQuery to **2.1.1**. I was using **Chrome Version 35** for testing.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Are you down voting me for a suggestion?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I could understand why it was downvoted as it really did not supply an answer. Suggestions should be made as comments.

Comment: Hi @skymook - Wordpress is bundled with jQuery 1.11.0 so it may well be that it works with the latest version. I've always read best practice for WP devs is to use the bundled version. I'll post back my findings but thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @JayBlanchard fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

Found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7987341/11047), that addresses the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined".

> If .attr("class") returns undefined, you can't call .split on it because .split is a method of the String object and can't be called on undefined. You need to store the result of .attr("class") and then only split it if it is not undefined.

But I've tried your code locally and it works.

The only thing I can see that could cause an error (depending on the browser used) is that you've declared `var src` twice.
`$('script').each(function(index, value) {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    src = src || 'no source';
    console.log(src);
});`

Answer (score -3):

I think it is. If you can create a fiddle we can tell better, but what is happening is `attr('src')` is returning undefined, and then you are trying to call a function/property on that. Basically a null exception.

I would just test for 'src' being defined before you try to manipulate it.

Comment: Fiddle does not allow placing external js or js in the html section, which is what we are working with here, so I'm afraid I don't think I can make a fiddle. Fiddlesticks.

Comment: there is a comment function for these kind of 'proposuals'.

Comment: @raison if you test for it being undefined does that solve your problem?

Comment: Don't, think so - do you mean: if($(this) !== undefined) { - thanks

Comment: Yeah if you are getting a doesn't support function, its probably not returning a string when you call attr('src')